# VBA Find value of second to last row

Tags: vba

I'm currently having trouble in VBA with finding the second last value in a row.

I can currently find the last value in the row with End(xlToLeft).Value, but how do I find the value just before that?

I would use the offset function but there are spaces and the worksheet is dynamic so I can't use the offset function. how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you create a variable for the last column then just set the value to itself -2

e.g 
    dim Lastcolumn as integer
    Lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    Lastcolumn = Lastcolumn - 2

Comment: Will this work if the spaces are dynamic? There isn't exactly 2 spaces between each value.

Comment: no this would hard code the value into Lastcolumn. Maybe use a for each statement to check for the next cell in the row that has a value.

Comment: I would need it to be dynamic. Not every value is 2 spaces away from each other. Some are 3 some are 4.

Comment: are there values in these other cells or are they empty

Answer (score 0):

not sure of the exact syntax but something like the following

```
for each cell in cells
    if cell is notnothing then
       ' add your code here to use the value
    end if
next
```

Comment: But I only need the last two values. Why would I need to cycle through the entire row?

Comment: add an exit for at the end of your if block to exit out of the loop when a value is found